# PostgreSQL / PostGIS geocodes

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a table with clients containing a field with the name of the districts in which they live. 
The client The data I have imported from an Access database and is now as a table in PosgreSQL / PostGIS but no geometry exists.
I have also one shapefile with all districts that is already imported as a Table in POstgreSQL / PostGIS.

Whats is the Sql code so as to have each clients represented as a point based on district names?

Att: There is a field on each table with the names of distrits.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Your Question is missing a question. You seem to have a goal, but questions here are expected to show some effort toward achieving that goal.  In this case, where do you expect to get the points associated with the users?  From the district centroid?  Do the district names in the Access table match those of the geometry table? What happens if more than one customer is in a district?  What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! We need you to express an actual *question*! But keep in mind that our rules require you to include what you have done so far and where you are stuck exactly; if it's code you need to debug/improve, include the current state of it. It would help if you'd add your desired outcome in a more technical way, and/or add the actual goal of your endeavor; a point per district can be anything, even if a centroid might be the obvious choice. _if_ having the _same point_ per district for _every_ client is what you _should_ be looking for is a very different line of question...